# Как спрятать картинки одну под другую для галереи

Tags: javascript, jquery

Всем здравствуйте.

Столкнулся с такой проблемой.

Нужно вывести по клику картинки. 
Дело обстоит в том что для плагина **baguetteBox** нужно картинки в таком формате

---

```
<div class="gallery ">
    <a href="img/0198f9f765/3cef5c8.jpeg">
        <img src="img/0198f9f765/3cef5c8.jpeg">
    </a>
    <a href="img/0198f9f765/80c3556.jpeg">
        <img src="img/0198f9f765/80c3556.jpeg">
    </a>
    <a href="img/0198f9f765/5068354.jpeg">
        <img src="img/0198f9f765/5068354.jpeg"> 
    </a>
    <a href="img/0198f9f765/b6332fc.jpeg">
        <img src="img/0198f9f765/b6332fc.jpeg">
    </a>
</div>
```

---

У меня на каждое событие своя "пачка" картинок, и я по событийно вывожу картини на страницу.

И того у меня получается

```
<div class="gallery ">
    <a href="img/0198f9f765/3cef5c8.jpeg">
        <img src="img/0198f9f765/3cef5c8.jpeg">
    </a>
</div>
```

---

Вот кусок кода которым я вывожу картинки

```
      if (data.contents) {
    var prod = '';

    var $wrapper = $('#allproducts');

    for (var ix in data.contents[page]) {
    prod += '<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">';
        prod += '<div class="thumbnail gallery">';
            let ctn=data.contents[page][ix]['src'].length;
            for(let i=0;i<ctn+1;i++) {
                prod += '<a href="' + data.contents[page][ix]['src'][i] + '">';
                    prod += '<img style="z-index:'+i*10+'" id="' + ix + '" src="' + data.contents[page][ix]['src'][i] + '"';
                                  prod += 'alt="' + data.contents[page][ix]['alternate'][i] + '"';
                                  prod += '/>';
                                  prod += '</a>';
                };
                prod += '<div class="caption">';
                    prod += '<p>' + data.contents[page][ix]['small_text'] + '</p>';
                    prod += '</div>';
                prod += '</div>';
        prod += '</div>';
    }
    $wrapper.html(prod);
}
```

---

Задача обстоит в следующем как под одной картинкой спрятать остальные. Дабы потом выводить все картинки по клику.
И что бы картинки "прятались" одна под другую.

Comment: `position absolute or relative` и `z-index`

Comment: style="z-index:'+i*10+'" вот так и делаю но чего то не получается как хотелось бы(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот с `position:absolute;` можно сделать  то что вы хотели.

Там я добавил `js` скрипт просто для того что бы вы увидели какая картинка бы не была первой все ровно они один под другим.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  function getRandomInt(min, max) {
      return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
  }
  $('.rand').on('click', function(){
    var rand_el = getRandomInt(3,4);    
    $('.gallery').prepend($('.gallery>a:nth-child('+rand_el+')'));
  });
});
```

```css
.gallery{
  position: relative;
}
.gallery>a{
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.gallery>a:nth-child(1){
  z-index: 4;
}
.gallery>a:nth-child(2){
  z-index: 3;
}
.gallery>a:nth-child(3){
  z-index: 2;
}
.gallery>a:nth-child(4){
  z-index: 1;
}
.gallery>a>img{
  max-width: 100%;
}
.rand{
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="rand">Click me</div>
<div class="gallery ">
<a href="img/0198f9f765/3cef5c8.jpeg">
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/EPDlQ.png">
</a>
<a href="img/0198f9f765/80c3556.jpeg">
<img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQ3fGDQrr3u_7ar8mzH3Sy49Oja7XSvdGCv-kE_BTNPfp10mJow">
</a>
<a href="img/0198f9f765/5068354.jpeg">
<img src="https://www.shareicon.net/download/2015/09/29/109012_media.ico"> 
</a>
<a href="img/0198f9f765/b6332fc.jpeg">
<img src="http://www.alexyork.net/images/social/stackoverflow-color-512.png">
</a>
</div>
```

Comment: конечно все стили плывут но идея ясна.

Comment: @dpi Ну да потому что на примере некоторые картинки здесь у меня с фоном `transparent`. Но главное ведь не это))))